# Preciso "Copiar" o retorno de um Label no tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Salve Pessoal, estou com uma questão onde, tenho um código python onde faço um request em um API, assim solicito os dados via Entry do tkinter, porem preciso que o resultado que ele me gere de para o usuário "Copiar".

Segue código

```
    from cgitb import text
from os import link
from tokenize import String
from turtle import back
import requests
from tkinter import *


def buscaBoleto():
    boleto = vboleto.get()
    token = vtoken.get()

    url = "www.teste.com.br" + boleto + "?api_token=" + token
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    start = '"secure_url":"'
    end = '","customer_id'
    s = response.text
    #link = (s.split(start))[1].split(end)[0]
    link = 'www.teste.com.br/12345678'

    if s == '{"errors":"Unauthorized"}':
        resposta["text"] = str("Não Autorizado, tente novamente")
    else:
        resposta["text"] = link


janela = Tk()

janela.title("Visualizador de boletos")
janela.geometry("400x300")
janela.configure(background="#dde")

Label(janela,text="Insira ID:",background="#dde",foreground="#009",anchor=W).place(x=10,y=20, width=200, height=20)
vboleto=Entry(janela)
vboleto.place(x=10,y=40, width=200, height=20)

Label(janela,text="Insira o token:",background="#dde",foreground="#009",anchor=W).place(x=10,y=80, width=200, height=20)
vtoken=Entry(janela)
vtoken.place(x=10,y=100, width=200, height=20)

Button(janela, text="Gerar", command=buscaBoleto).place(x=10, y=140, width=100, height=20)


resposta = Label(janela,text="",background="#dde",foreground="#009",state="normal",anchor=W)
resposta.place(x=10,y=200, width=400, height=20)



janela = mainloop()
```

O que ocorre que jogo o resultado do link gerado para o campo:

```
    if s == '{"errors":"Unauthorized"}':
        resposta["text"] = str("Não Autorizado, tente novamente")
    else:
        resposta["text"] = link

resposta = Label(janela,text="",background="#dde",foreground="#009",state="normal",anchor=W)
resposta.place(x=10,y=200, width=400, height=20)
```

Existe algum jeito melhor, que possa fazer eu conseguir "Copiar" esse resultado gerado na tela do tkinter?

Segue imagem de anexo do que preciso.
[exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qKxa.png)

Answer (score -2):

O tkinter tem uma funcão interna derivada da classe Tk chamada clipboard_append, creio que solucione teu problema.

Segue um exemplo...

```py
from tkinter import *


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry('200x200')
        pads = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}

        self.entry_var = StringVar()
        entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry_var)
        entry.pack(**pads)

        btn = Button(self, text='Copiar', command=self.copiar)
        btn.pack(**pads)

        debug_label = Label(self, textvariable=self.entry_var)
        debug_label.pack(fill='x', **pads)

    def copiar(self):
        self.clipboard_clear()
        self.clipboard_append(self.entry_var.get())


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```